# Help verifying a Fourier Transform identity

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I don't know why I keep getting stuck, but I'm having trouble verifying the following identity from one of my textbooks:

$$\chi(T(\lambda - \lambda_j)) = \frac{1}{T\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\chi}(t/T) e^{it \lambda} \cos(t\lambda_j) \,dt + \chi(T(\lambda+\lambda_j))$$

I know that I need to separate the complex exponential, and use Euler's identity, but I'm having trouble getting the $\chi(T(\lambda + \lambda_j))$ term to work out. My computations keep coming up with $\chi(T(\lambda_j - \lambda))$.

I don't think it's important to the calculation, but $T>1$, $\lambda,\lambda_j \geq 0$, and $\chi$ is a Schwartz class function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which textbook is it Patch ?

Comment: @Isham "Hangzhou Lectures of Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian", top of pp. 125.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that the sign of the last term is not a minus sign ? On the RHS

Comment: I mean $$\chi(T(\lambda - \lambda_j)) = \frac{1}{T\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\chi}(t/T) e^{it \lambda} \cos(t\lambda_j) \,dt - \chi(T(\lambda+\lambda_j))$$

Comment: That's another one of my questions. *I* get a minus sign, like you suggest, but the author definitely claims "plus". (In words, because the equation is too large to fit on one line.) On the other hand, though, we are only trying to talk about asymptotic behavior in $\lambda$, and I think a sign error wouldn't change the big oh behavior.

Comment: Its the Fourier Transform. Normally I can prove the claim but it must be a minus sign

Comment: The part that was keeping me stuck was the changing of $\lambda-\lambda_j$ on the LHS into $\lambda+\lambda_j$ on the RHS.

Comment: You  simply apply  the Shift theorem for Fourier Transform thats all Patch

Comment: I have the book what page is it Patch so I can check in my book version

Comment: I mentioned it above: top of pp. 125

Comment: Yes the author wrote clearly "plus"...

Comment: But he put the expression after "plus" on right  left side not on the left side.

Comment: I was in class and hadn't looked through your solution, but it's missing now???

Comment: Oh sorry i deleted it since it dosent really solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\chi(T(\lambda - \lambda_j)) = \frac{1}{T\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\chi}(t/T) e^{it \lambda} \cos(t\lambda_j) \,dt + \chi(T(\lambda+\lambda_j))$$
$$\chi(T(\lambda - \lambda_j)) -\chi(T(\lambda+\lambda_j))= \frac{1}{T\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\chi}(t/T) e^{it \lambda} \cos(t\lambda_j) \,dt $$
You just need to prove this :
$$\chi(T(\lambda + \lambda_j)) = \frac{1}{2\pi T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\chi}(t/T) e^{it \lambda} e^{i(t\lambda_j)} \,dt $$
$$\chi(T(\lambda + \lambda_j)) = \mathscr {F^{-1}}\left \{\frac{1}{ T} \hat{\chi}(t/T)  e^{i(t\lambda_j)} \right \}  $$
$$\mathscr{F}\left \{\chi(T(\lambda + \lambda_j)) \right \}  =  \frac{1}{ T} \hat{\chi}(t/T)  e^{i(t\lambda_j)}  $$
And also:
$$\mathscr{F}\left \{\chi(T(\lambda - \lambda_j)) \right \}  =  \frac{1}{ T} \hat{\chi}(t/T)  e^{-i(t\lambda_j)}  $$
You first scale then you shift. Thats correct.

Maybe there is a typo in the book. Because the sign on the LHS should be a minus sign
$$\chi(T(\lambda - \lambda_j)) = \frac{1}{T\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\chi}(t/T) e^{it \lambda} \cos(t\lambda_j) \,dt \color {blue}{-\chi(T(\lambda+\lambda_j))}$$

Comment: I guess the fourth time's the charm! I guess I just kept dropping a minus sign, but I finally got the correct result, WITH A MINUS as you pointed out. Thanks for the  help.

Comment: Patch you are welcome......@Patch